# Keep scrolling while user press left/right keys on the keyboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have successfully added the ability to scroll (left/right) when left/right key on the keyboard are pressed

```
$('body').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: "-=980"
        }, 1000);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) { // right
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: "+=980"
        }, 1000);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It works pretty well when the user press only one time on the left/right keys. When the user press left/right for a long time, the scolling effect is stopped then started again (as long as the key is pressed).

**I would prefer the scroll is not stopped/started again when user press left/right for a long time.** BUT continuing scrolling until the left/right button is released.

Possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Just an Idea,  `onKeyDown --> boolMove = true`,   `onKeyUp --> boolMove = false` which was what exactly Ran mentioned in his post.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, I think it is possible. 
Try to use in the onKeyDown event

```
setInterval()
```

Calling your scrolling function every 200 ms or so.

Then use the onKeyUp event to stop the function (using a flag or using clearInterval())

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I am not an expert with jQuery but I'll try with setInterval & a boolean like boolMove. The hardest part may be to keep actual code for keyDown event and add things for onKeyDown...

Comment: Try and You Will Succeed! If not, we are here